# How do I find out how and why my question was removed?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I just noticed in my reputation listing on my scifi profile:

> -1 2 days ago
>
> -1 03:00 remove What is the exact step by step process of Borg assimilation?

Why was my question removed? I had no warning, and no message was sent to me notifying me this happened. The question was well within the guidelines. I was told at meta.stackexchange.com: "You'll want meta.scifi.stackexchange.com –  Billy Mailman 2 mins ago" to repost my question here.

I cannot even find this question anymore, does it still exist? I can edit it if necessary.

Comment: since you lost 1 rep when it was removed, it probably had 1 upvote (+5) and two downvotes (-2 each) for a net score of 1. While you are not notified when questions are closed (I think you should be) the downvotes should be a warning. Typically editing is the right thing to do at that point.

Comment: @KateGregory Why is this question too broad? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89353/what-is-the-exact-step-by-step-process-of-borg-assimilation

Comment: I don't have enough rep to see deleted questions so I can't answer that.

Comment: @KateGregory you can't click on that link? "What is the exact step by step process of Borg assimilation? [closed] We were having this discussion in some comment lines, so I thought I'd throw this question out there. Hopefully the others commentators will chime in on this.

I did do some research on this.

From the Wikipedia article on the Borg: (I did not include the quote) 

So here are the main parts that I'm concerned about in terms of this question:

What is involved step by step in assimilating an individual?
Are nanites required at all, a necessary step, or just one of...

Comment: <cont'd> several ways to get to create a drone.
Are prosthetics and implants required at all, a necessary step, or just one of several ways to create a drone?
What is the step by step process, and if there is more than one process please describe as many as you know of to get from an individual to a fully matured Borg drone.

On a side note, do they really remove the reproductive organs? 7 of 9 didn't have female sex organs? Picard's were removed? Hugh's manhood was taken from him? @KateGregory

Comment: So that is at least 4 questions. Why not ask one about nanites, one about reproductive organs, etc. Too Broad covers things where a good answer would be very long and this seems to cover that perfectly. (And as for your click the link issue, yes, if a low rep user clicks a link to a deleted question they just see "this question was deleted" - you need 10k to see deleted posts.)

Comment: @KateGregory I was forced to do that once before. A bunch of people disagreed with the Mod forcing me to do that. It was about phase shifts with Voyager. The problem was they were all related. I went ahead and re-asked the question with multiple questions. We ended up with the primary question not being answered at all. The other questions ended up with answers that didn't take the other questions into consideration(since they were all already the same question really). It got so convoluted in that case that it wasn't worth my time putting links to the other questions, etc.

Comment: @KateGregory If I did as you suggest, which I won't, here is what would happen. On the question of nanites the answer would be yes. One the question of prosthetics the answer would be yes. On the process I'd be given that there are nodules the borg inject people with, nanites get into the person, the person becomes a borg. None of that is what I am looking for. Cumulatively, what I am trying to figure out is that since the process seems to not be consistent, is that simply unanswerable, did the process change, is there more then one way to do it, etc. Separating them does nothing for me.

Answer (score 5):

It still exists, you should be able to find it through the link at the bottom-left of your [questions profile page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40599/jmfb?tab=questions), "deleted recent questions."  You'll find it was automatically "deleted by Community♦ 2 days ago," as is liable to happen to closed questions. [Rules for automatic deletion here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/172958):

> - Automatic deletion of closed, abandoned questions for questions meeting the following criteria:
>
>   - Closed more than 9 days ago
>   - Not closed as a duplicate
>   - Score <= 0
>   - Not locked
>   - No answers with a score > 0
>   - No accepted answer
>   - No pending reopen votes
>   - No edits in the past 9 days

Comment: **<comments removed>** Everyone, go cool off.